# Is an NSMutableString in this case more efficient than NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I declare a pointer variable in this fashion:

```
NSString *foo;
```

And then somewhere later in my code do something such as:

```
foo = @"bar";
```

Is that ultimately taking my NSString, creating a new copy in memory with an additional string, then deleting my initial string? Would foo be better off as an NSMutableString?

Answer (score 9):

No, `foo` is variable holding a pointer to an `NSString`. The assignment `foo = @"bar"` sets the value stored by the pointer `foo` to the address of the NSString `@"bar"`. There is no copy made. If `foo` already pointed to an other `NSString` instance that *was not* a string constsant (i.e. like `@"bar"`) and there are no other references to that instance, then you have a memory leak. You would

```
[foo release];
foo = @"bar";
```

in that case. You do not need to retain or release string constants like `@"bar"`.

String constants cannot be mutated, so you will get a runtime error if you try to modify the value of a constant string. There's no difference between assigning `@"bar"` to an `NSString*` vs an `NSMutableString*`. Of course, you won't be able to use the mutating methods of the `NSMutableString` without a runtime error just because you assign the address of @"bar" (an NSString instance) to a variable of type `NSMutableString*`. If you want to mutate the string, you would do

```
NSMutableString *mutableFoo = [@"bar" mutableCopy];
```

In this case, a copy is obviously made and you are responsible for releasing `mutableFoo` when you're done with it.

Comment: foo isn't a pointer; it's a variable holding a pointer. And the assignment doesn't change the value pointed to; that's what Coocoo thought it did, and it's wrong. The assignment replaces the pointer with a pointer to @"bar".

Comment: Also, there's no difference between assigning @"bar" to an NSString *variable vs. an NSMutableString *variable, period. No exceptions, and you'll get the runtime error from sending mutation messages to an immutable string no matter where you assigned the pointer.

Comment: I'll make the type of foo clearer. But assignment to foo does change the value of foo and the value assigned is the address of @"bar". If you think there is a clearer way to say that, please edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The @"bar" in your example is a string constant, and should be baked into your code.  You don't need to worry about memory allocation / deallocation with this constant.

NSMutableString is more efficient to use when you are doing a lot of little manipulations to a string (appending substrings, etc.) and you don't want to keep allocating autoreleased NSStrings all over the place.  I tend to avoid autoreleased strings on the iPhone if I can, due to memory concerns within loops.