# Some beginner Objective-C/iPhone questions

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm just starting out (reading up a lot for the past couple of days). Here's some questions that I have stacked up, hopefully someone can answer them.

**1.** the (self != nil) check in initializer code. Why do it? To prevent accidental access to some "run-only-once" code that's wrapped up in there? Where from could this accidental access come from? Doing such checks suggest that I don't have control over what's going on.

`- (id)init {
    self = [super init]
    if (self != nil) {
    // Code..
    }
    return self;
}`

**2.** How is it that you don't have to free up anything that static methods return? (or this is the idea I've got)

**3.** How is str = @"Hi there!" different from

`str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"];`

As I understand, you have to release str in aquired with second method, but not with first? If so, when does the first one get released? Which one is preferable (not minding the typing length)?

**4.** What is autorelease, if iphone has no garbage collection? I've noticed something called "an autorelease pool" being created in main.m. Is [myObject autorelease]; a way of adding myObject to the nearest wrapping "autorelease pool", which will release it? Basically, some magic to avoid releasing it yourself? Why use it?

Well, thats it for now. Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. In Objective-C, it's possible to return an instance other than self from `-init`. Classes do this, for example, to enforce a singleton instance, or in the case of class clusters. `NSNumber`, for example, returns a subclass depending on the type of value passed to its initializer. So when you call `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithLong:long_value]`, `NSNumber`'s `-initWithLong:` initializer is called after `NSNumber`'s `+alloc`, but a subclass of `NSNumber` may be returned to the oringial caller. Thus the pattern

   self = [super init];

   which reassigns `self` to the value of `[super init]` so that `self` points to the actual instance that `[super init]` returned. If `+alloc` or the super's `init` method fails, the result of `[super init]` may be `nil`. To avoid, side effects in the case of a failed initialization, the pattern then becomes

   > ```
   > - (id) init {
   >   if(self = [super init]) {
   >     // do initialization of instance variables etc.
   >   }
   >
   >   return self;
   > }
   > ```

   Note that you must return `self` (or `nil` or an other instance) from the `init` method. You *should* assign self to `[super init]` and you may check for `nil` before doing more work.
2. You may have to release the return value of a staic method. You should read the Cocoa memory management [guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). The rule is generally quite simple: If the method you call has "new", "alloc", or "copy" in its signature, the result belongs to the caller and the caller must call `-release` on that instance or there will be a memory leak. Of course you should call `-retain` on anything else (i.e. not from an "alloc","new" or "copy" method) you want to keep a reference to and then call `-release` or `-autorelease` when you are done with that instance.
3. `str = @"Hi there!"`, assuming `str` was declared as `NSString *str;` assigns the address of the string constant `@"Hi there!" to the value of the`str`variable. You do not need to retain or release string constants.`str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"];`allocates a new string instance. The value of`str`will be the address of this instance. Each call of`str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"];`again will allocate a new instance. So after`str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"];`,`str != str2`, while after`str2 = @"Hi There!", `str==str2`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706519/is-an-nsmutablestring-in-this-case-more-efficient-than-nsstring/706610#706610) answer as well.
4. `-autorelease` adds the receiver to the current `NSAutoreleasPool`. When the pool is drained (usually at the end of the current run loop iteration, or when the pool is manually drained), the pool calls `-release` on all instances in the pool. If this `-release` drops the retain count to 0, the object is deallocated (and `-dealloc` called) just as with any other `-release`. Using an autorelease pool is generally frowned upon on the iPhone because it may cause you to accumulate many unused instances in the pool before it is drained at the end of the run loop iteration. If you can use `-release` instead of `-autorelease`, you generally should. Again, see the Cocoa memory management [guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for more info.

Comment: Such a well thougth out, filled with examples reply. Thank you, most of it is clear now. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a school of thought that in most cases, allocating the `self` pointer is something that the system should do, and not the programmer.

Also, many people prefer to keep the main line of program flow as un-indented as possible. In which case the initialisation code could be re-written as:

```
- (id)init {
    if (![super init]) {
        return nil; // There is a problem so bail early.
    }
    // Initialisation code here.
    return self
}
```

[Will Shipley](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html) explains this much better than I do.

Comment: Thanks, that blog post was very helpful. And confusing. I understand it talks about Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch, so maybe doing this check is still valid for reasons mentioned by others in iPhone environment (out of memory situations)?

Comment: If you are just starting out, it might be confusing. I brought it up as an example that there are other ways of writing even simple things as initialisers. Bookmark Wil's "Pimp My Code" series and go back to it after a few months; you'll find it useful for thinking about writing Cocoa/Obj-C code.

Comment: Objective-C is the language. Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are frameworks. Although some patterns differ between the two, the principles of Objective-C (including the init pattern) apply to both.

Answer (score 1):

1: This check is to ensure that the super constructor returned a new object.

2: Static methods don't refer to an instance

3:

`str = @"Hi there!"`

This assigns the address of the constant string "Hi there!" to the pointer str

`str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"];`

This allocates a string and copies "Hi There!" to it. This means that a) str is modifiable and b) needs to be deallocated when you are done with it.

Comment: But in general sense, both str usages would consume same amounts of memory, just that the first one is immutable. Doesn't using the second method guarantee the space is freed whenever I need it? Simply asigning @"Hi there!" takes up space too, no? But no control over that space in memory, right?

Comment: NSString is immutable, so str is not modifiable in either instance.

Comment: No, str is a mutable container for an immutable string.

Comment: Brian, so basically, it's possible to change the value of str using the second method, by releasing current value and allocating a new one? How would that be done? [str release]; str = [[NSString... ?

Answer (score 1):

calling

```
self = [super init];
```

May return nil if the superclass cannot initialize itself for some reason or other, including memory being unavailable, or certain prerequisites have not been met.  If that is the case, you don't want to be trying to set variables of self, or set self as a delegate, or add self to an array, if self is nil.

The autorelease pool is something created upon every event the iPhone sends your application.  It is created before any code runs, and released after all your code is done, for each event.  Any objects that you call `autorelease` on will be put into the current autorelease pool.  Any objects in the autorelease pool will be released as many times as they were added, after your code completes.  In this way, you don't have to worry about who's responsible for releasing an object created by one method and returned to another method.

You can create your own autorelease pools as necessary.

```
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"];
```

This line creates a string that is not in an autorelease pool, so you have to release it manually.  Simply writing

```
@"Hi there!";
```

returns a string that you don't have to worry about releasing.  Extending your previous example:

```
str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there!"] autorelease];
```

would be another method of creating a string you don't need to worry about releasing.

One difference between garbage collection and autorelease pools is that garbage collection works with circular references.  Using autorelease pools, you don't want to have two objects that retain each other and hope that once nothing else refers to them, they will go out of existence; they won't.

Comment: So the benefit of putting objects into autorelease pools is not having to release them manually, but the drawback is loosing control on *when* to release it? Basically, if I give my object to autorelease pool, I'm at it's mercy for releasing it whenever that happens?

Comment: You may lose control of when you release it, but not when it becomes deallocated.  If you want to keep around an object that has been placed in an autorelease pool, you can simply call [obj retain] so that its retain count is still larger than 1 after the autorelease pool releases it.

Answer (score 1):

1. If *self* is *nil* after the super initialisation then you're probably out of memory. Your only reasonable course of action is to return nil and hope things get handled gracefully further up the stack.
2. Static methods aren't allowed allocate on the heap, therefore there's nothing to free.
3. In the first instance, the string is compiled into the data segment of your app and cannot be freed. In the second instance, you are allocating memory from the heap and copying your static string (from the data segment) into it.
4. It's simple garbage collection. As to why to use it, the simple answer is don't. It's not recommended to use autorelease on the iPhone due to limited resources.

Comment: So basically, str = @"Hi there!" sits in this data segment for the whole  app runtime, regardless of wether the code portion doing the asignment is reached or not? In other words, the more such strings I have, the more memory my app will require initially? Thanks

Comment: "Hi there!" sits in the bss section, str (that is, the storage for the 4-8 bytes it takes to represent an address) sits in the data section. str is initialized with the address of the string in the bss section.