# What is the right way to know if an object was initialized in a database?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a trouble in my database - somehow at some point it appears that a database is being closed even before it was opened.

If a database was not opened I am using the following statement: if (!database) then break;

when *database is being set to nil (database = nil) when it was not opened.

Am I doing it in a right way? Or there is some other error in my code?

Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL) loadDB: (NSString*) dbPath {

//Database was opened before
if (database) {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    database = nil;
}

//Opening database
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    database = nil;
    return FALSE;
}

return TRUE;
```

}

The code is being called for multiple times and at some time it throws an exception. Why may this happen?

When I am using debugger to see where a problem occured, it shows me: sqlite3_close(database);

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is database set to nil on the first instantiation of this object?  Since we have but a code snippet, it's hard to tell how many other places database can get touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the database pointer to NULL instead of nil.

```
-(BOOL) loadDB: (NSString*) dbPath {
    BOOL retVal = TRUE

    //Database was opened before
    if (database) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        database = NULL; // <-- NULL not nil
    }

    //Opening database
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        database = NULL; // <-- NULL not nil
        retVal = FALSE;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

In Objective C nil is a nil pointer on an object. But `database` is a pointer to a struct, so use NULL instead.

Comment: too bad he doesn't care to know the answer (or has solved it and not posted the resolution).

Comment: He accepted my answer on the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720603/sqlite3close-throws-an-exception/720739#720739

Answer (score 1):

Your close brace is too early (but I don't think that's the problem because it wouldn't compile.

As a style note, please only return ONE time from a function (and make that at the bottom).  Create a BOOL, initialize it to TRUE and change it's value to FALSE when necessary.

Comment: Multiple returns are useful in certain conditions, so I wouldn't take that as a rule, personally.

Comment: multiple returns mean your function is too large - finding multiple returns isn't just a smell, it's a maintenance stench.

Comment: I redesigned my code according to your recommendation but this didn't help.

Comment: When I am using debugger to see where a problem occured, it shows me:  sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: @kevindtimm in this example, multiple returns are stinky and my answer below shows a different way of doing it. But, two returns are common in code where it is a guard condition. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710568/some-beginner-objective-c-iphone-questions/710986#710986

Comment: @Abizem - that's probably the only case where I would 'agree' with multiple (only two) returns.  I would agree with the indentation assumption, that certainly does hold some credence.